# How to define fix numbers and/or chars with ngx-mask

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

```
<input formControlName="someNumber" mask="0000.00" />
```

Using [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask), this would force me to enter 1234.56 - but let's say I only want to accept 99 as the last two digits, how would I need to define the mask? Can't make it work with custom patterns...

Answer (score 0):

It should be a mask with a suffix i think;

```
<input formControlName="someNumber" suffix=".99" mask="0000"/>
```